# Closing my message box and root window in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, dialog, exit, box

## import statements

```
import from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime
now = strftime( "%x %Z %X")
```

## Setting window

```
root=Tk()
root.title("ON TOP OF THE WORLD")
canvas= Canvas(root, width=350, height=250)
canvas.pack()
photo=PhotoImage(file='/Users/m/Desktop/TOTW.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=photo)
```

## Welcome User

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Hello,today is", now)
```

## ask user

```
name=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("name","What is your name?" )
```

## input process

```
output = "Hello, %s! May the only place you find yourself today is on top of the world !" %name
```

## show output

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(now, output)
```

## CLOSE

```
def on_closing():
    if tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol(on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

## I need help in closing or ending this dialogue box

Comment: So.. What is your question? Do you get any error? What do you expect and how this code works? You should elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could take two other approaches to this, one being quit() and simply ending the code all together, or using frames in tkinter and calling a different frame whether it says close or comes up blank. It would be able to cover everything already there